# How to get source location of #includes using clang libtooling?

Tags: include, clang, libtooling

Is there any way to get `clang::SourceLocation` for every `#include` in file by its `clang::FileID` or `clang::FileEntry` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using source manager's GetIncludedLoc function which takes fileid as parameter.

SourceManager.GetIncludedLoc(fileid)

Comment: Once I have the include location, how do I navigate between the includes include? I'm using this to inject an include statement but it goes before the comments of the copyright which is not what I want.

Comment: This is a good tip, but the method name is `getIncludeLoc` (and has been since its [introduction](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/commit/61ef3db22246)).

Answer (score 1):

Thank's @Hemant for your answer, you're right

I Already found that by myself (in clang 3.8 it is called `getIncludeLoc`)
but forgot to write here.
I used this to find the location after all #includes where i can put my own.
Here's the function (For sure not the best way) I wrote for this, hope it helps someone

```
SourceLocation getIncludeLocation(FileID fileID, SourceManager &sm, unsigned carriages) {
       return SourceLocation();
     set<unsigned> lines;
    if (fileID.isInvalid())
    for (auto it = sm.fileinfo_begin(); it != sm.fileinfo_end(); it++) {
        SourceLocation includeLoc = sm.getIncludeLoc(sm.translateFile(it->first));
        if (includeLoc.isValid() && sm.isInFileID(includeLoc, fileID)) {
            lines.insert(sm.getSpellingLineNumber(includeLoc));
        }
    }
    unsigned pos(0);
    if (!lines.empty()) {
        bool first = true;
        for (unsigned line :lines) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else if ((line - pos) > carriages)
                break;
            pos = line;
            //cout << "Include line:" << pos << endl;
        }
        //cout << console_hline('-') << endl;
    }
    cout << sm.getFileEntryForID(fileID)->getName() << endl;
    return sm.translateFileLineCol(sm.getFileEntryForID(fileID), ++pos, 1);
}
```

Also some information about includes can be get by

```
Preprocessor::GetIncludeFilenameSpelling(SourceLocation Loc, StringRef &Buffer)
```

and

```
Lexer::ComputePreamble(StringRef Buffer, const LangOptions &LangOpts, unsigned MaxLines = 0)
```