# clang libtooling insert a new header safely

Tags: c, libclang, libtooling

I'm using clang's libtooling to modify some code and I'm trying to find a way to safely insert a header whenever my tool is used on a C file.

I've read [What's the right way to match #includes (or #defines) using Clang's libtooling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27029313/whats-the-right-way-to-match-includes-or-defines-using-clangs-libtooling) question about match calls to the preprocessors but I'm still uncertain about using it to insert code.

What is the proper way to insert a new #include using libtooling rewriter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK it is possible (The proposed variants are for c ++ but with some changes can be used for c).

I don't know what do you mean by "safely insert", 
but I see two ways:

1. Inserting `#include` near existing one. The problem here is to find
   existing `#include`. The possible way to do it  described here:
   https://stackoverflow.com/a/44077744/6490190
2. Inserting include before the topmost `TranslationUnitDecl` or
   `NamespaceDecl` in AST. The idea is to start from some `Stmt` or
   `Decl` or `Type` in code and recursively visit all its parents:
   `ASTContext::getParents()` until `TranslationUnitDecl` or
   `NamespaceDecl` is found.

   Example can be found here:

   - https://github.com/YulyIllarionov/Cpp-14-Regress/blob/master/cpp14regress/inc/lambda.h,
   - https://github.com/YulyIllarionov/Cpp-14-Regress/blob/master/cpp14regress/src/lambda.cpp

Comment: I no longer need this but for the next poor soul who stumble across this I'll mark this as the correct answer.